# Pandas: vectorization of Conditional Cumulative Sum

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a for loop in pandas to improve performance. I have a dataset comprising of users, products, the date of each service as well as the number of days supplied. Given the following subset of data:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data={"USERID": ["A"] * 6,
                            "PRODUCTID": [1] * 6,
                            "SERVICEDATE": [datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(
                                2016, 2, 5),
                             datetime(2016, 2, 28), datetime(2016, 3, 25),
                             datetime(2016, 4, 30), datetime(2016, 5, 30)],
                            "DAYSSUPPLY": [30] * 6})

testdf=testdf.set_index(["USERID", "PRODUCTID"])
testdf["datediff"] = testdf["SERVICEDATE"].diff()
testdf.loc[testdf["datediff"].notnull(), "datediff"] = testdf.loc[
    testdf["datediff"].notnull(), "datediff"].apply(lambda x: x.days)
testdf["datediff"] = testdf["datediff"].fillna(0)
testdf["datediff"] = pd.to_numeric(testdf["datediff"])
testdf["over_under"] = testdf["DAYSSUPPLY"].shift() - testdf["datediff"]
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
                  DAYSSUPPLY SERVICEDATE  datediff  over_under  desired
USERID PRODUCTID                                                       
A      1                  30  2016-01-01         0         NaN        0
       1                  30  2016-02-05        35        -5.0        0
       1                  30  2016-02-28        23         7.0        7
       1                  30  2016-03-25        26         4.0       11
       1                  30  2016-04-30        36        -6.0        5
       1                  30  2016-05-30        30         0.0        5
```

Essentially, I want my desired column to be the running sum of over_under, but to only sum the negative values if the value of desired on the previous line is > 0. desired should never get below 0. A quick and dirty loop over a [user, product] group looks something like this:

```
running_total = 0
desired_loop = []
for row in testdf.itertuples():
    over_under=row[4]
    # skip first row
    if pd.isnull(over_under):
        desired_loop.append(0)
        continue
    running_total += over_under
    running_total = max(running_total, 0)
    desired_loop.append(running_total)
testdf["desired_loop"] = desired_loop

                  desired_loop
USERID PRODUCTID              
A      1                   0.0
       1                   0.0
       1                   7.0
       1                  11.0
       1                   5.0
       1                   5.0
```

I'm still new to vectorization and pandas and general. I've been able to vectorize every other calculation in this df, but this special case of a cumulative sum I just can't figure out how to go about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it using a somewhat unconventional iteration.

```
testdf["desired"] = testdf["over_under"].cumsum()
current = np.argmax( testdf["desired"] < 0 )
while current != 0:
    testdf.loc[current:,"desired"] += testdf["desired"][current] # adjust the cumsum going forward
    # the previous statement also implicitly sets
    # testdf.loc[current, "desired"] = 0
    current = np.argmax( testdf["desired"][current:] < 0 )
```

In essence, you are finding all the "events" and readjusting the running cumsum over time. All of the manipulation and test operations are vectorized, so if your `desired` column doesn't cross negative too often, you should be pretty fast.

It's definitely a hack but it got the job done for me.